# Is the play "Rosencrantz and Guildenstern" ever mentioned in the series?

Tags: plot-explanation, props, the-marvelous-mrs-maisel

I was reading [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/118208/what-is-rosencrantz-and-guildenstern-in-the-marvelous-mrs-maisel-season-3-e) and I re-watched the episode 6 in season 3 of *The Marvelous Mrs. Maisel*.

This green notice for the play "Rosencrantz and Guildenstern" is somewhat prominent in the screen for around a minute, but does it have any significance to the plot of the episode or the series? Is the play itself or the author/director/actors in it ever mentioned in another episode?